# Only show rows with the most recent date join view

Tags: mysql, view

I am trying to run this view.

```
select `AM`.`athleteID` AS `athleteid`,
       `AM`.`maxLift` AS `maxlift`,
       `AM`.`dateofmax` AS `dateofmax`,
       `TP`.`date` AS `date`,
       `TP`.`teamID` AS `teamID`,
       `TSP`.`trainingSessionProgramID` AS `trainingSessionProgramID`,
       `TSP`.`trainingSessionKey` AS `trainingSessionKey`,
       `E`.`exerciseName` AS `exerciseName`,
       `RS`.`repScheme` AS `repScheme`,
       `RS`.`percentage` AS `percentage`,
       `TSP`.`exerciseID` AS `exerciseID`,
       `TSP`.`repSchemeID` AS `repSchemeID` 
from ((((`dutchIron`.`tblExercises` `E` 
         left join `dutchIron`.`tblTrainingSessionProgramming` `TSP` 
                    on((`E`.`exerciseID` = `TSP`.`exerciseID`))) 
         left join `dutchIron`.`tblRepSchemes` `RS` 
                   on((`RS`.`repSchemeID` = `TSP`.`repSchemeID`))) 
         left join `dutchIron`.`tblProgramming` `TP` 
                   on((`TP`.`trainingSessionKey` = `TSP`.`trainingSessionKey`))) 
         left join `dutchIron`.`tblAthleteMaxs` `AM` 
                   on((`AM`.`exerciseID` = `E`.`exerciseID`)))
```

I am recording a max lift weight in `tblAthleteMaxs`. However, when I run the query a get multiple sets of rows depending on how many max weight values (`AM.maxLift`) I have in the table. Ideally, I just want to select the most recent max weight value (`AM.dateofmax`) and have the view return just those rows. Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

Here is what is returned currently. Ideally I just want the ones with 500 as maxlift based on the fact that it is a later date. Right now it includes all of the 345 rows as well.

[image: imageofcurrentview]

I've review the repeat post, but none of it makes sense to me. I just need all the rows that have the latest dateofmax. Doing a max(dateofmax) doesn't work because it just pulls one record. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: you should not write your sql code on a single  row

Comment: Apologies. OK, can you explain what the guidelines are for me to format future questions?

Comment: for sql code  .. you can write the code on several rows .. eg one column for row and so on .. i have edited  the first 3 you can do the rest  .. and you should also add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Is there a best way to add proper data sample, and expected result?

Comment: use a tabular  text format   .. (as a select .... text result)